# SQL Server correct way to account for the weekend

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, excel, date

I have a few sql statements where I manually enter the date everyday then execute.

I would like to automate the date part. But weekends are giving me trouble. I use excel to run the reports as it is then saved and another member of staff does a mailshot.

This is my test example:

```
if (datename(dw, getdate()) = 'Friday') BEGIN
select convert(varchar, dateadd(day, 7, DATEADD(dd, 0, DATEDIFF(dd, 0,getdate()))), 103)
 + ',' + convert(varchar, dateadd(day, 9, DATEADD(dd, 0, DATEDIFF(dd, 0,getdate()))), 103) AS [Date] END
ELSE BEGIN select convert(varchar, dateadd(day, 7, DATEADD(dd, 0, DATEDIFF(dd, 0,getdate()))), 103) as [Date] END;
```

But how would I put this into a sql where statement?

for example

```
select * from table where (date = )
```

where Date equals 7 days in advance unless It's Friday when we have to account for the weekend so we want 7,8 and 9 days in advance?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
select * from table where date = (case
  when datename(dw, getdate()) = 'Friday' then
    convert(varchar, dateadd(day, 7, DATEADD(dd, 0, DATEDIFF(dd, 0,getdate()))), 103)
     + ',' + convert(varchar, dateadd(day, 9, DATEADD(dd, 0, DATEDIFF(dd, 0,getdate()))), 103)
  else
    convert(varchar, dateadd(day, 7, DATEADD(dd, 0, DATEDIFF(dd, 0,getdate()))), 103)
  end)
```

Comment: Could you be more specific please?
Also i need to avoid @@datefirst because of incorrect settings on the server.

Comment: checking if datepart(dw, getdate()) = @@datefirst is a better way to check if it's Monday. Changing your if to a case is the answer for how to put your condition into a where clause. I'll edit it to be more clear